SMARTSHEET Formula using HAS(ANCESTOR(Column@row)) is not working properly on applicable child rows
There are three applicable columns in my ~9K row smartsheet page.
Column "Add" - defined as type "checkbox" but allowing other characters.  Text color set to white, so that I can put an x or X in that column to disappear the checkbox on most rows.
Column "IsHeaderRow" (a normally hidden column) that has a column formula:
=IF(UPPER(Add@row) <> "X", 1, 0)
(This will provide detection of all rows that do not have an x in the Add column, IE I want the user of the sheet to be able to tick the Add checkbox and this column will detect which rows have that enabled)
This is a checkbox type column that only allows checkbox values.
Column "Required" - Another checkbox type column (allowing only checkbox, no other characters.  Also normally hidden)
The problem is how the column formula I am trying to apply to the "Required" column (used for filtering the sheet) is working.
The formula is this:
=IF(IsHeaderRow@row = 1, Add@row, IF(HAS(ANCESTORS(Required@row), 1), 1, 0))
The theory is, if the row in question has the IsHeaderRow value detecting the section header row, match the row value for the Add checkbox.  This works completely fine.
The problem comes in for all children (multiple nested children up to maybe max 4).
The second part of that IF statement is the IF(HAS(ANCESTORS(Required@row), 1), 1, 0)
The way I understand this is, The IF gets TRUE and should set the Checkbox to TRUE if any of its parent rows also have the Required Checkbox set.
So if I check the Add checkbox, this should set the Required checkbox on the parent line, and all subsequent child lines should also pull that from the parent line.
This does not happen however.
If I play with the First IF statement and remove the nested IF, I can set the values in the rows fine.
For example, If I input:
=IF(IsHeaderRow@row = 1, Add@row, 1)
We will see the entire Required Column for all children populate with a checkbox. (The parent row will only set to 1 if I also Check the Add box - as you would expect).
I also tried changing this:
=IF(IsHeaderRow@row = 1, Add@row, IF(HAS(ANCESTORS(Required@row), 1), 1, 0))
to this:
=IF(IsHeaderRow@row = 1, Add@row, IF(HAS(ANCESTORS(Add@row), 1), 1, 0))
I was thinking maybe there is some kind of recursion issue with the same formula setting the parent row fine, but breaking for the child rows....
Maybe its still some kind of weird issue there, but changing it to reference the Add row which I would reason should work the same also did not work.
I'm not sure what flavor / version of smartsheet I am using and not seeing how to check from within the interface.
